# Set first and last row of a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've been reading over this and still find the subject a little confusing :
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Say I have a Pandas DataFrame and I wish to simultaneously set the first and last row elements of a single column to whatever value. I can do this :

`df.iloc[[0, -1]].mycol = [1, 2]`

which tells me `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.` and that this is potentially dangerous.

I could use `.loc` instead, but then I need to know the index of the first and last rows ( in constrast, `.iloc` allows me to access by location ).

What's the safest Pandasy way to do this ?

To get to this point :

```
# Django queryset
query = market.stats_set.annotate(distance=F("end_date") - query_date)

# Generate a dataframe from this queryset, and order by distance
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(query.values("distance", *fields), coerce_float=True)
df = df.sort_values("distance").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then, I try calling `df.distance.iloc[[0, -1]] = [1, 2]`. This raises the warning.

Comment: does `df['mycol'].iloc[[0, -1]] = [1, 2]` work?

Comment: Same warning, whether I index rows or column first.

Comment: You'll need to show exactly all steps that lead to the warning as my answer shows that this works correctly

Comment: Edited my original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't with `iloc`, it's when you access `.mycol` that a copy is created.  You can do this all within `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[[0, -1], df.columns.get_loc('mycol')] = [1, 2]
```

Usually `ix` is used if you want mixed integer and label based access, but doesn't work in this case since `-1` isn't actually in the index, and apparently `ix` isn't smart enough to know it should be the last index.

Comment: Ah ! That's where the copy is created. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is called chained indexing, you can use `iloc` just on that column to avoid the warning:

```
In [24]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))

Out[24]:
          a         b         c
0  1.589940  0.735713 -1.158907
1  0.485653  0.044611  0.070907
2  1.123221 -0.862393 -0.807051
3  0.338653 -0.734169 -0.070471
4  0.344794  1.095861 -1.300339

In [25]:
df['a'].iloc[[0,-1]] ='foo'
df

Out[25]:
          a         b         c
0       foo  0.735713 -1.158907
1  0.485653  0.044611  0.070907
2   1.12322 -0.862393 -0.807051
3  0.338653 -0.734169 -0.070471
4       foo  1.095861 -1.300339
```

If you do it the other way then it raises the warning:

```
In [27]:
df.iloc[[0,-1]]['a'] ='foo'

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.1\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\__main__.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Comment: Actually, `df.mycol.iloc[[0, -1]]` still raises a warning for me. I'm on 0.17.1. I wonder if it's because it was created using `pd.DataFrame.from_records`, because when I run yours, no warning.

Comment: I had the same issue on 0.18.0.  When I ran the code above I didn't get the warning, but the warning was raised when I used the same method on some test data I created.  Strange.

Comment: Occasionally makes you wish that Python made the notion of pointers more explicit ;)